# Combining enscript, find, iconv and ps2pdf

Tags: command-line, find, pdf, enscript

I'm trying to write a small bash script that'll convert source files in a directory to a .pdf. The steps are these

- Locate files with find
- execute iconv on the files converting the character encoding from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 via finds -exec
- pass this output through enscript and eventually ps2pdf

The only reason I've added iconv is that enscript does not support utf-8.
So far I've made the following mess:

```
#!/bin/bash
enscript --portrait --columns=1 --header ' $n|'"$2"'|%F  Page $% of $=' --highlight='java' --line-numbers --output='-' --color --font='Courier8' `find $1 -name '*.java' -type f -exec iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 {} +` | ps2pdf - "$2"'.pdf'
```

Running it give me this output: enscript: invalid option -- ',' Try `enscript --help' for more information.

Edit:
It did not give that error before I added -exec iconv.
2. edit:
The original formulation I made was vague I see now. Heres the original script I tried to modify:

```
#!/bin/bash
`which enscript` --portrait --columns=1 --header ' $n|'"$2"'|%F  Page $% of $=' --highlight='java' --line-numbers --output='-' --color --font='Courier8' `find $1'/src/' -name '*.java'` | ps2pdf - "$2"'.pdf'
```

./script.sh target_dir output_file_name

The original script combines all source files  in a folder recursively into one single pdf with each file starting at a fresh page. Maybe I just got to live with having to do this in two steps. First converting charset and then converting to pdf.

Comment: While I cannot tell what's wrong with your line by looking at it, it could help to try prepending it with `echo` and checking that the expanded line is what you are actually expecting it to be. Doing so may oftentimes help you see the problem in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

Create a java2ps script to easying the parameter handling

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENSCRIPT="
--portrait
--columns=1
--font=Courier8
--highlight=java
--color
--line-numbers
--output=-
"

iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 "$1" \
| enscript --header=' $n|'"$1"'|%F  Page $% of $='
```

Now, the execution is simple

```
find -name '*.java' -type f -exec ~/java2ps {} \; | ps2pdf - > all.pdf
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply. This gives a pdf for each source file. I was looking for a single file combining all source files into one.

Comment: I have changed it for single output file.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. Now I just need to figure out how to make a decent header/footer with enscript and wrap it all into a one step process.